# Convert a Laravel Builder response to a Collection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've got 3 tables - challenge, challenge_users, and climbs with the following definitions:

```
table challenge
  id, name, start_date, end_date

table challenge_users
  id, challenge_id, user_id

table climbs
  id, user_id, date
```

I want to pull a list of climbs that fall within the dates of the challenge for any user in the challenge.  The following SQL query does what I want:

```
select 
  * 
from 
  climbs c 
join 
  challenge_user cu on c.user_id=cu.user_id 
where 
  date >= '2015-03-01' 
  and date <= '2015-03-06' 
  and cu.challenge_id=1;
```

I can build this with a query builder like

```
$climbs = DB::table('climbs')
    ->join('challenge_user', 'climbs.user_id', '=', 'challenge_user.user_id')
    ->where('climbs.date', '>=', $this->start_datetime->tz($tz)->startOfDay()->toDateString())
    ->where('climbs.date', '<', $this->end_datetime->tz($tz)->endOfDay()->toDateString())
    ->where('climbs.date', '<=', Carbon::now()->tz($tz)->endOfDay()->toDateString())
    ->get();
```

The problem is, this return an array of arrays.  What I really want is to get a Collection of Climb models.  I know I can do something like Climb::all()->filter(...), but then I'm doing a pretty large select (the SQL query ends up just being "select * from climbs").

Is there a way to use the DB to limit my results but still get my Collection of Climb models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Eloquent with a join, but you need to manually specify the select statement so that you're only getting the fields from the parent table and not the joined table:

```
$climbs = Climb::select('climbs.*')
    ->join('challenge_user', 'climbs.user_id', '=', 'challenge_user.user_id')
    ->where('climbs.date', '>=', $this->start_datetime->tz($tz)->startOfDay()->toDateString())
    ->where('climbs.date', '<', $this->end_datetime->tz($tz)->endOfDay()->toDateString())
    ->where('climbs.date', '<=', Carbon::now()->tz($tz)->endOfDay()->toDateString())
    ->get();
```